# Vote up system open to non-registered users

Tags: voting-system

Hi I'm thinking to implement a simple Thumb Up vote system.
The problem is that I want to let the vote system open even to users not registered to web site and at the same time I'd like to track if a user has already voted (best situation would be give the user the chance to delete a vote).

Are cookies the best option? What about if a visitor has cookies disabled?

Any advice is more then appreciate!

Thanks a lot
P.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways to do this: you can track users by computer or by IP.

If you track by computer, using cookies is your best bet; however, that is a client-side solution, and like you've pointed out, users with cookies disabled can bypass that.

Using IP to track users has the advantage of being server-side (and therefore can't be disabled by users); however, there are issues with multiple users being on the same public IP, users moving between places, etc. It's much less reliable than tracking using cookies.

In my opinion, cookies are your best option. It's much more reliable, and if they don't have cookies enabled, then you can test for that and maybe just not give them a vote (or fall through to IP tracking).

Comment: I'm actually thinking about cookies but beside the fact that cookies might be disabled I'm wondering how can I track multiple informations in one single cookie. I mean there are several elements that a visitor can vote on the web site. Do I have to create a cookie for every vote? Or it's a good idea to use also a Vote_table in the db in order to track the voting system?

Comment: What you can do is make a log file on your server (or an entry in your database, depending on how you roll), which holds a set of data for each unique key (which is generated if the user doesn't have a cookie and maintained if they do); then you save the key value to the cookie.

Comment: My idea was, at the first vote I create a random string 30 chars (letters and numbers) and I write it on the cookie and in the DB (in a table dedicated to the tb_vote_system). In tb_vote_system I can memorize the ID of the element voted and its table (for example tb_web_sites). So I will have tb_vote_system with USER_ID_RANDOM_30CHARS | ID_ELEMENT_VOTED | TB_WHERE_THE_ELEMENT_DATA_ARE_STORED . So before the vote I'll check if the cookie with 30chars string exists (if not means is the first vote ever in my site) if yes I check if the 30chars string is linked to ID_ELEMENT and TB_ELEMENT.

Comment: That sounds fine to me, and should (hopefully) work. Give it a try.